# gwt style nth-child collide with first-child

Tags: css, gwt, css-selectors

I want to define a set of CSS rules for my FlexTable in GWT. I've defined 4 different rules for all combinations of odd and even.

```
.myTable tbody tr:nth-child\(odd\) td:nth-child\(odd\) {
    background: #EEEEDD;
}
```

It works very well, but now I want to define separate style for first row of table. I tried to do something like this:

```
.myTable tbody tr:first-child {
    background: #123456;
}
```

but it doesn't work with 4 previous rules. It is ignored. Do you have any suggestions how to define separate style for the first row of table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you applied the background to the `td` elements in your first rule, you need to apply it to the `td` elements in the second rule.

Assuming you want the same different background for all cells in the entire first row:

```
.myTable tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child\(even\), 
.myTable tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child\(odd\) {
    background: #123456;
}
```

To make that shorter, here's a trick, using `:nth-child(n)` to match all `td` elements:

```
.myTable tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child\(n\) {
    background: #123456;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock . I've tried your code and I must admit you are almoust right :) It should be:

    .myTable tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child\(even\) {
        background: #123456;
    }

    .myTable tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child\(odd\) {
        background: #123456;
    }

Comment: @Grzes: Ah, yes, the pseudo-classes were overriding it. I edited my answer with something that avoids code duplication.